# Variable scope in nested function "Class" structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, scope

So I'm in the process of porting a Python application over to Node.js, for various reasons. I've got moderate Javascript knowledge via web development, but have been having some issues with variable scope and (possibly?) some asynchronous calls I'm making.

So, I've got a nested method "xmlToObjectByType" in my DataLoader class that I'm trying to potentially set variables in, based on some matching criteria in a series of XML files. No matter what I do in the method, products never changes from null, and the xml_files.splice() call never works. I'm positive it's a scoping issue *(code inside parseString which is inside fs.readFile, which is inside forEach, etc etc)* but I haven't been able to find much luck figuring out exactly why or how to correctly get the value set.

As a last ditch I tried getting the result in a callback set on xmlToObjectByType, which gets me the value I'm looking for, but I still can't set the value of `products` from the callback. I'm sure it has to do with scoping, but I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm sure this is a really simple thing I'm overlooking, but it's been a long time since I've dove this deeply into JS. Which isn't very deep at all. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here, aside from the probably terrible logic flow?

Note that this is a simplified version where I took out the checks for a few other XML file types, for legibility reasons.

**Code**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');


export function DataLoader(working_directory){  
  var working_directory = working_directory;
  var xml_files = [];
  var products = null;
  var data = null;

  var xmlToObjectByType = function(type, setValue) {
    xml_files.forEach(function(file, index) {
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        fs.readFile(working_directory + '/' + file, function(err, data) {
            parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                if (result.Products.Product) {
                    var result_object = result.Products.Product;
                    // check if we've got at least one row, else return false
                    if (result_object.length > 0) {

                        // products specific check
                        if (type == "products") {
                            // identify products XML with artist tag
                            if (result_object[0].Artist) {
                                // this is a products XML file, so pop this file from xml_files, return object
                                xml_files.splice(index, 1);
                                setValue(result_object);
                            } 
                        }

                    } else {
                        // no rows in object
                        setValue("no rows");
                    }
                } else {
                    // ROW object isn't set, malformed XML
                    setValue("malformed XML");
                }
            });
        });
    })
  }

  // check selected directory for XML files
    fs.readdir(working_directory,function(err,files){
        if(err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            // do something with each file HERE!
            if (file.split('.').pop() == "xml") {
                xml_files.push(file);
            }
        });

            // if they don't exist return and send message
            if (xml_files.length < 1) {
                var status = {status: "error", message: "There are no XML files in the directory you selected."};
            } else {

                // process further
                xmlToObjectByType("products", function(result) {
                    products = result;
                });


                data = {"products": products};

                // products always has the value null here
                console.log(data);
            }

            return status;
     });
};
```

**I'm calling it via**

```
import { DataLoader } from './my_module';
DataLoader('/Path/To/XML');
```

**And a simplified example of an XML file (i think i did this right)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Artist>Test</Artist>
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Description>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Artist>Test</Artist>
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Description>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Artist>Test</Artist>
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Description>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Artist>Test</Artist>
        <Title>Test Title</Title>
        <Description>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</Description>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macmee is correct in that your `data` and `product` variables are only changing within the scope of the `xmlToObjectByType` callback, which is being called asynchronously (the next tick of the processor, after you've requested the result to be logged to console).

But I think your main problem is not-so-much your handling of the data, but at which point in the code you're requesting for feedback about the data.

So, with your current code, `products` *is* getting populated with an Object representing the XML, but it's just being populated far after you've asked it to be printed back to you. You can test this theory by placing a simple timed function which will report back the results in half a second:

```
/* ... code before */

var working_directory = working_directory;
var xml_files = [];
var products = null;
var data = null;

setTimeout(function(){

  console.log(products);

}, 500);

/* code after... */
```

So, what you really want is a `callback` for the `DataLoader` in general:

```
function DataLoader(working_directory, callback){
```

And call it in your XML parsing callback:

```
xmlToObjectByType("products", function(result) {
    callback({"products": result});
});
```

And then call your `DataLoader` like so:

```
DataLoader('/Path/To/XML', function(data){ console.log(data) });
```

With these adjustments to the code, I'm getting this output in my console:

```
{ products: 
   [ { Artist: [Object], Title: [Object], Description: [Object] },
     { Artist: [Object], Title: [Object], Description: [Object] },
     { Artist: [Object], Title: [Object], Description: [Object] },
     { Artist: [Object], Title: [Object], Description: [Object] }
   ]
}
```

Obviously I'm making some assumptions about your user-case. But I think this demonstrates how you can navigate the different scopes in asynchronous JavaScript.

***Update***

Here's a re-write of your application that will collate data from multiple XML files and then callback with the data:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js'),
    path = require('path');


export function DataLoader (directory, callback) {  

  getXmlFiles( function (files) {

    parseXmlFile(files, callback);

  } );

  function parseXmlFile (files, callback) {

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    var data = {};
    var filesLeft = files.length;

    files.forEach( function(file, i) {

      fs.readFile( path.join(directory, file), function (err, result) {

        parser.parseString( result, function (err, result) {

          if (result.Products.Product) {

            var result_object = result.Products.Product;

            if (result_object.length > 0 && result_object[0].Artist) {

              data[file] = result_object;

            }
          }

          filesLeft--;

          if (!filesLeft)
            callback(data);

        });
      });
    });
  }

  function getXmlFiles (callback) {

    var files = [];

    fs.readdir(directory, function (err, f) {

      if(err) throw err;

      f.forEach( function (file) {

        if (file.split('.').pop() == "xml") {

          files.push(file);

        }
      });

      callback(files);

    });
  }
}
```

Use it with something like this:

```
DataLoader( __dirname, function (data) {

  console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: So it looks like I missed the async clues on a few levels. This totally makes sense and works. The one thing I'm a little fuzzy on, and I don't mention in the question for the sake of brevity: I actually end up calling xmlToObjectByType three times for three different XML file type-checks; wondering if there's a sane way to fire the callback with results from all three xmlToObjectByType calls once they've fired... my initial thought is putting the xmlToObj calls inside of the callback, but I can see why that obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking yourself the right questions. To get what you're after, you have to know what scopes you're creating, when they're being created and when they yield results. This is where the asynchronous world can trip people up at first. It requires a little adjusting. What I've done is updated my answer with a rewrite of your module which will put a second load of XML data in the returned data. If you can try and fellow it, it should demonstrate how you might go about dealing with scope/asynchronous problems in the future.

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing that—not necessary but great to see. This totally makes sense how the callback piggybacks along the functions, and also makes sense why it can throw someone off. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this part here:

```
xmlToObjectByType("products", function(result) {
    products = result;
});

data = {"products": products};
console.log(data);
```

the callback to `xmlToObjectByType` I am assuming is asynchronous, therefore:

```
data = {"products": products};
console.log(data);
```

this will run before:

```
products = result;
```

which means when you set a value to `data` it will be undefined. Try:

```
xmlToObjectByType("products", function(result) {
    products = result;
    data = {"products": products};
    callback(status, data); // see below
});
```

and `DataLoader` will have to now take a callback if you want to access `data` after calling `DataLoader`:

```
function DataLoader(working_directory, callback)
```

then where you call `DataLoader` you will need to do:

```
DataLoader(.., function(status, data) {
  // do stuff with status and data
})
```

Comment: Yep, that totally makes sense--- I guess I was halfway there and just didn't see that after staring at it for so long. Will confirm but pretty sure it was that simple!

Comment: So that makes sense from that context, I'm able to set data there, but I'm not able to get that data variable outside of the fs.readdir call in the main function; it looks like that's still outside of the scope (or is it an async problem in actuality?)

Comment: I guess I should say that ultimately I'm wanting to return the data value from the main DataLoader() function, out into the wild, wild world.